# How to create progress dialog for a received JSONObject with Volley while it is inserted in SQLite?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-volley

I used Volley to get Data of type String from MySQL Server.

I get my JSONObject and save it in my SQLite using the following in the Volley Response

```
for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
    try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            MyClient ClientFromObject = new MyClient(json);
            db.AddClient(ClientFromObject);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If I put a simple progress dialog in any position after or before db.AddClient(ClientFromObject) **I get my dialog AFTER data are inserted!**

I created a Dialog containing a new thread passing there my JSONObject but its not working either

using

```
public void showDialog(final JSONObject ClientObject) {



    final int MaxCount = 2000;
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.success);
    pDialog.setMax(MaxCount);
    pDialog.setMessage("Wait");
    pDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pDialog.show();

    final Handler handle = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            pDialog.incrementProgressBy(10);
        }
    };
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (pDialog.getProgress() <= MaxCount)
                {

                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    db.AddClient(ClientObject);  
                    handle.sendMessage(handle.obtainMessage());



                    if (pDialog.getProgress() == pDialog.getMax())
                    {
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

SO how to create a progress dialog for a downloaded JSONObject when I inserting it in SQLite Database?!

Thank you